# Creating Selection MapTool in PyQGIS Custom Application

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm developing a custom GIS application using the PyQGIS API.

How can I let the user select features on the map using Maptools? I would like to replicate the select feature there in Qgis to make the selection on the click of a button.

My understanding is to use `layer.selectedFeatures()` function, but I am not sure of how to add the Selection Maptool to the mapcanvas and toolbar.

Comment: Please keep to the site format of only ONE question per thread. I'll remove the second one, please repost it.

Answer (score 6):

The selection map tools are not part of the qgis libs. You therefore have to reimplement the behavior if you are writing a custom app.

### Maptool implementation

You will have to subclass qgis.gui.[QgsMapTool](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html) and implement the *canvasPressEvent*, *canvasMoveEvent* and then modify the layer selection according to this.

You can have a look at the source files of the existing selection maptools ( e.g. [qgsmaptoolselectpolygon.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/app/qgsmaptoolselectpolygon.cpp) ). They are C++ code, but pretty simple and should explain the concept.

### Add to the mapcanvas

You will have to call the method *setMapTool* of your [QgsMapCanvas](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html) instance and pass an instance of your own selection map tool as parameter.

```
myMapcanvas.setMapTool( mySelectionTool )
```

### Toolbar

You have to create an action and connect its triggered signal to a method (slot) where you will set the map tool as outlined in the last paragraph.